# Bootloader tutorials don't work for me

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I've tried using some of the assembly tutorials around the web, and most of them don't work for me. I'm using NASM, and VirtualBox (Couldn't get Bochs to work either), and stuff like this works:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]
push 0xB800
pop es
mov byte [es:0],'A'
mov byte [es:1],0x1F
jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

but this doesn't:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]
mov ah,0x09
mov al,'A'
mov bh,0
mov bl,0x1F
mov cx,1
int 0x10
jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

I'm using this batch script I made:

```
:: Compile with NASM ::
@echo off
echo Compiling boot.asm to boot.bin
cd C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/Assembly

C:/nasm/nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin

:: Copy to a floppy image with bfi ::
echo Creating boot.img

cd C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/Assembly
timeout 1 >nul
C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/Assembly/bfi -b=boot.bin -t=4 -l="Boot" -f=boot.img

:: Start Virtual Machine ::
echo Starting Virtual Machine "Test"

timeout 1 >nul
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" controlvm "Test" poweroff
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" startvm "Test"
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

I also tried ndisasm -b 16 boot.img, as suggested, but it just repeatedly outputs div dh? (this is on the working version)

Comment: Try using qEmu, or somehow get Bochs working (post on SuperUser if you're having problems with those -- I might be able to help, and so might others). They have internal mini-debuggers that let you view memory, registers, etc., which is pretty useful for stuff like this.

Comment: If you disassemble boot.img with `ndisasm -b 16 boot.img`, do you get the same code or not?

Comment: It's possible the BIOS has not set the video mode to what you think it is. Have you tried initialising it with INT 0x10 (AH=0) first? Maybe also reset the cursor position using INT 0x10 (AH=2). You're also assuming the stack pointer is valid - many bootloaders reset SS:SP on entry (just to make sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bootloader, you won't have a valid stack, you'll need to set that up yourself.  Any stack ops (which you're invoking with the INT) are fraught with peril if you don't *know* you have a good stack!

Comment: The stack that the BIOS uses when it loads the boot sector is perfectly valid. It's the same stack that the BIOS uses "when invoking with the INT" during setup.